# Display line breaks in text area using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form with select tag and a text area. Content of the text area is dynamically displayed based on the select tag value.

At the same time user can change the text area value and saved it.

When page loads the text area value is displayed via jQuery from a hidden field value.

The problem I am having is with line breaks.

I do following when I display the text area value

```
var original_content = $('#original_customer_text').val().replace(/\r/g,"\r").replace(/\n/g,"\n");
```

but results is displayed like this

```
line 1 goes here
              line 2 goes here
              line 3 goes here
```

how do I remove the spacing in second and third line when displaying value in text area ?

Comment: You want to retain newlines or removing them is ok?

Comment: I want to retaining new lines but remove the tab like spacing in line 2 and line 3 as it confuses users of the system